# Got unexpected result after forced the string to be executed in bash

Tags: bash

```
str="python"
$($str)
```

python was **started normally**, but when i exited, the following message came:

> bash: : command not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just `$a`. The brackets here is not necessary.

Comment: `$(${a})` expands into a $( python ), which is a command substitution. Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the command substitution  with  the  standard output of the command. What do you need is a `python`, not `$(python)`.